# Number of Non negative integer solutions of $3a+2b+c+d=19$

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-coefficients, systems-of-equations, integers

Find Number of Non negative  integer solutions of $3a+2b+c+d=19$

My attempt:

we have $$2b+c+d=19-3a$$ Required solutions is coefficient of $t^{19-3a}$ in

$$( 1-t^2)^{-1}(1-t)^{-1}(1-t)^{-1}=\frac{1}{(1-t)^3(1+t)}$$

By partial fractions we get

$$( 1-t^2)^{-1}(1-t)^{-1}(1-t)^{-1}=\frac{1}{2}\times (1-t)^{-3}+\frac{1}{4} \times (1-t)^{-2}+\frac{1}{4}\times (1-t^2)^{-1}$$

Required coefficient is

$$\frac{1}{2} \sum_{a=0}^{6} \binom{21-3a}{2}+\frac{1}{4} \sum_{a=0}^{6}\binom{20-3a}{1}+\frac{1}{4}(4)=294+\frac{77}{4}+1$$

why i am not getting integer answer?

Comment: Because you made a mistake in your partial fractions calculation. http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=partial+fractions+(1-t%5E2)%5E-1(1-t)%5E-1(1-t)%5E-1

Comment: No check it once its matching with wolfram result

Comment: Sorry, you are correct. I see the error now; it should be $\frac14(3)$. There are three values of $a$ for which $19-3a$ is even and nonnegative (and thus receives a contribution from $(1-t^2)^{-1}$), namely $a=1,3$ and $5$.

Answer (score 1):

HINT.-Checking directly is not hard.
$$3a+2b=19$$ has only three solutions $(1,8),(3,5),(5,2)$.

When $a=6$,$$2b+c+d=1$$ has two solutions $(0,0,1),(0,1,0)$.

When $a=5$, $$2b+c+d=4$$ has five solutions from which one has to be discarded $(1,1,1)(2,0,0),(0,1,3),(0,2,2),(0,3,1)$ we have till now
$$(1,8,0,0),(3,5,0,0),(5,2,0,0)\\(6,0,0,1),(6,0,1,0)\\(5,1,1,1),(5,0,1,3),(5,0,2,2),(5,0,3,1)$$ There are nine solutions as far and we can continue with the remaining values of $a$.